# How to list files in a unmounted ext4 file without mouinting it

Tags: ext4

So say if I did `mkfs.ext4` on a 1 GB file to make an ext4 file system then mounted it and add the file `cat.ls` unmounted it and sent it to B computer that did not have sudo (note I will not use fuse) how would the person read the file without mounting it. Edit you can install any ext4 parser, you just can't mount it.

Edit to get the ext 4 file you would run this `dd if=/dev/zero of=ext4 bs=MiB count=1024 ;mkfs.ext4 ext4 ; mkdir ext4dir ; sudo mount ./ext4 ./ext4dir ;sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ext4dir ;echo hel > ext4dir/cat.ls ; sudo umount ext4dir` now how would computer b parse the ext4 file or dump the file to a directory

Comment: Unless the person at B can read raw disk blocks, and understands how to find the right disk partition, and understands how ext4 works, they cannot access the file. What's the system at B? Will it automount the disk at `/media/$USER/volumename`?

Comment: no mounting no auto mounting non of that

Comment: Hello. What you are trying to do is impossible. You would get the same result as if the disk was in another room and you tried to read it.

Comment: Why would you want/need this?

Comment: how would reading from a ext4 file / img how would that be impossible the data is in a regular file with all the ext4 data in it all you would need to do is parse it

Comment: and "Why would you want/need this?" that does not rely mater i ask a question could have a need, so it is a valid question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 7-Zip archiver `7z` can also read (though not write) many types of filesystem image files and devices, including ext4, just as if they were zip files.

For example, you can list all the files in the image with the command:

```
7z l ext4image
```

And extract a specific file with:

```
7z x ext4image cat.ls
```

`7z` is probably already installed, but it can be installed with:

```
sudo apt install p7zip-full
```